# How to compiled pdo_dblib for MAMP 3.3?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, mamp

I am using MAMP to connect to ms sql server. I need to use pdo_dblib.so. However I have an issue to compile it.

At this point, I already install latest freedts

The way I did it was, I download php 5.4.42 from php.net

```
cd php5.4.42/ext/pdo_dblib
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-pdo-    dblib=/usr/local/freetds/
make
```

I copy module/pdo_dblib.so to /Application/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.42/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/

I update PHP 5.4.42 php.ini to include extensions=pdo_dblib.so

When I run phpinfo, pdo_dblib is not exists.

Is there something wrong with what I did ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my issue, updating FreeTDS version to 8 in freetds.conf fix the issue.